# create a powerForm from template with custom envelop fields API

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts, docusignconnect

For application integration purposes, I need to create via DocuSign REST API powerForms from a predefined template. The powerForms should have **envelop** custom field.
I'm using powerForm since I want to share link to recipient and not via email.

What is Docusign Rest API URL and body to create the powerForm with envelop custom field?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint to create powerforms is:

```
{baseURI}|/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/powerforms
```

You can find codesamples to create a powerfrom from your teamplates here:
[create a powerForm from template with custom envelop fields API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71831044/create-a-powerform-from-template-with-custom-envelop-fields-api)

Unfortunately it is not possible to provide an envelope custom field in the request to create the powerform. The envelope custom field has to already exist in the template you use